# Using reflection to set List<dynamic> to List<T>

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

Say, I have these properties in a class :

```
public class Example
{
    public List<Toyota> listToyota; 
    public List<Honda> listHonda; 
    public List<Huyndai> listHuyndai; 
    ... 
    ... 
}
```

And there will be more properties if there are new car brands. Each brand is a table.

Normally, I would do this to get the data from tables :

```
Example result = new Example();
switch (brandname)
{
    case "Toyota":
        result.listToyota = * select table from context * ; 
        break;
    case "Honda":
        result.listHonda = * select table from context * ; 
        break;
        ...
}
```

Also, I'll have to add more code when there are new brands. I found this very annoying/time-consuming and decided to switch to a dynamic approach. I've sucessfully get the tables dynamically :

```
tblName = "Toyota"; 
IEnumerable<dynamic> table = typeof(MyContext).GetProperty(tblName).GetValue(context, null) as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
```

But I failed to dynamically set the property value, in this example, is `listToyota` :

```
query = (from a in table select a).ToList() as List<dynamic>;
SetPropertyValue(result, "listToyota", query);
```

I got this error :

> Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Toyota]'.

`SetPropertyValue` is a very simple function using `System.Reflection` :

```
static void SetPropertyValue(object p, string propName, object value)
{
    Type t = p.GetType();

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(propName);

    if (info == null)
        return;
    if (!info.CanWrite)
        return;
    info.SetValue(p, value, null);
}
```

Any advices are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I feel that your initial approach is incorrect.. May I ask why you do not have some common base class for all of the different Brands? Why are they being separated? What are you trying to win with the `dynamic` approach?

Comment: My inital approach is working fine. The brands thing is just a illustration I made for easier understanding, it's not real

Comment: still, `dynamic` should be seen as a very last resort. It may solve some issue, but it introduces a heap of new issues IMO. Would it be possible to again [describe the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of the solution you are trying to implement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try something like this

```
static void SetPropertyValue(object p, string propName, object value)
{
    Type t = p.GetType();

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(propName);

    if (info == null)
        return;
    if (!info.CanWrite)
        return;

    var elemtype = info.PropertyType.GetElementType();
    var castmethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(elemtype);
    var tolist = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(elemtype);

    var collection = castmethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });
    var list = tolist.Invoke(null, new object[] { collection });

    info.SetValue(p, list, null);
}
```

Comment: edited. IEnumerable must be converted to list before assignment.

Comment: this line `var elemtype = info.PropertyType.GetElementType();` is returning a `null` value, do you have any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, should be `GetGenericArguments` instead of `GetElementType`, nice answer, you are a life saver !

Answer (score -1):

I think the main problem is your software design. I wouldn't use dynamic this way.

1. I would create a Brand-Class. If you want to use dynamic, try something like this:

   ```
   public class DynamicBrand : DynamicObject
   {
       private IDictionary<string, object> myDynamicValues;

       public DynamicBrand()
               : base()
       {
           myDynamicValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
       }

       public void AddMember(string Name, object Value)
       {
           if (!myDynamicValues.ContainsKey(Name.Trim().ToLower()))
           {
               myDynamicValues.Add(Name.ToLower().Trim(), Value);
           }
           else
           {
               throw new Exception("The Member with the Name: " + Name + " already exists!");
           }
       }
       public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder Binder, object Value)
       {
           if (myDynamicValues.ContainsKey(Binder.Name.ToLower()))
           {
               myDynamicValues[Binder.Name.ToLower()] = Value;
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               myDynamicValues.Add(Binder.Name.ToLower(), Value);
           }

           return true;
       }

       publc override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder Binder, out object Result)
       {
           if (myDynamicValues.ContainsKey(Binder.Name.ToLower()))
           {
               Result = myDynamicValues[Binder.Name.ToLower()];
               return true;
           }
           else
           {            
               Result = null;
               return false;
            }
       }
   ```
2. I would change your example class

   ```
   public class Example
   {
       // string = brand-name; list = list of dynamic brand items
       public Dictionary<string, List<DynamicBrand>> brands;
   }
   ```
3. Whenyou fill your data, just add a new dynamic brand to your brands-list and simply add the member you need.

**EDIT**: Dynamic isn't a very nice solution for your problem. I would think about a completly different structure.